# How to count in a sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

So this is the code i have.

```
SELECT TestName
FROM Testtype
WHERE TestID IN (Select TestID
                    from Tests
                    where Testno IN (Select Testno
                                      from Users
                                      WHERE StudentType= 'StudentType1'
                                      )
                    )
```

This produces Just a list of the name of the test that matches the Student type
so like

```
Test1
Test2
```

i am wanting so i can count how many matches for test1 there are so the output is like

```
No of student that undertook the test   Test Type
52                                      Test1
23                                      Test2
```

Any help appreciated , thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace subqueries with joins, and add `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT tt.TestName, COUNT(*) as NoOfStudents
FROM TestType tt
JOIN Tests t ON tt.TestID=t.TestID 
JOIN Users u ON t.Testno=u.Testno AND u.StudentType= 'StudentType1'
GROUP BY tt.TestName
```

Comment: Thanks , i thought it maybe be something like this

Answer (score 0):

Youcan use also this query.

```
SELECT TestName,count(*) StudentsCount
FROM Testtype tt,
     Tests t,
     Users usr
where usr.StudentType='StudentType1'
  and usr.Testno = t.Testno
  and t.TestID=tt.TestID
group by TestName
```